# AWS S3 CopyObject Version

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to implement "restore" object by creating a copy of an older object version.

I am using AWS PHP SDK 2, method [copyObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_copyObject), but I cannot find a way to specify versionID of the source object.

AWS REST API documentation ([ref](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/copyVersions.html)) mentions

> To copy a different version, use the versionId subresource.

but it is not mentioned in the SDK docs.

I tried to add the versionID to the "CopySource" attribute, SDK docs say that it is

> The name of the source bucket and key name of the source object, separated by a slash (/)

but it did not work.

```
$param = array(
  'Bucket' => $this->bucket,
  'CopySource' => urlencode($this->bucket . $this->delimiter . $source_key . $this->delimiter . $source_version_id),
  'Key' => $dest_key
);
$result = $this->s3Client->copyObject($param);
```

#### Question

How can I specify the versionID of the source object?

Comment: Could you post some code, please?

Comment: Please add the code to your question.

Comment: This question is also on the AWS forums: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=508381

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found an answer thanks to the [AWS Discussion forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=508381).
The right parameters setup is

```
$param = array(
  'Bucket' => $this->bucket,
  'CopySource' => urlencode($this->bucket . $this->delimiter . $source_key) . '?versionId=' . $source_version_id,
  'Key' => $dest_key
);
```